# First program with Apache Thrift - Where should I define the interface? in client or server code

Tags: java, php, thrift

I am making a php client which request a function from java service through apache thrift. I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/leric/php-thrift-package) for php client code. I need to understand something, the interface that's generated as file.thrift should be on client and server or only at one side?

And something else, in client code, how can I call the client object that call the server function? 
In the tutorial I follow this line

```
$client = new HbaseClient($protocol);
```

how he defined this class?

and in [apache thrift tutorial](https://thrift.apache.org/) he defeined the same in python client

```
# Create a client to use the protocol encoder
client = Calculator.Client(protocol)
```

the Calculator object is it the service provided from the server that identified in the interface? and same question the interface should be in both client and server ??

Please help, I am really stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am following this tutorial

Here are the real ones: http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/

> the interface that's generated as file.thrift should be on client and server or only at one side?

The starting point is the IDL file. IDL means Interface Definition Language and it is simply a file, which describes the API contract between a server and a client. The server's task is to implement the interface described in the contract so that the client can call it.

To put the IDL file to use, you run the Thruift Compiler to generate some code for both ends. If the server and the client are using the same language (say Java) it is enough to just generate the code one time and use it in both projects:

```
  thrift -r -gen java MyApiContract.thrift
```

creates a `gen-java` folder with the files in it.

If it happens that the server and the client are different types of code (e.g Java and PHP), then you will need to generate code for both of them:

```
  thrift -r -gen java -gen php MyApiContract.thrift
```

which will generate two folders, `gen-java` and `gen-php`, respectively.

Since Thrift is a cross-platform, cross-language framework, having client and server written in different languages is not such a unusual case at all.

Comment: what if the server already has it's own IDL and we need to add extra function that the client will use. I make new IDL in client and generate gen-php file and now stuck at the server side. I update the existing thrift file to add the new function  and generate the gen-java code but now cannot generate the jar file! it keeps giving me dependencies errors. Do u think the problem because it's different IDL or doesn't relate?

Comment: Some errors like this `cannot find symbol
    [javac]             org.apache.thrift.TSerializable msg` and `error: method hashCode in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]     hashCode = hashCode * 8191 + org.apache.thrift.TBaseHelper.hashCode(f1);` what should I do with this cases? these errors wasn't there before adding new function to thrift file!
I know it's not easy to figure it out, but if u just give me hints of what possible issues I can track.

Comment: I figure it out, the problem is about the version of thriftlib. I update the jar file and it works perfectly.